# How do I get a list of all used types?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I want to know if their is a way to get the list of all used types in a code.

If i load an assembly it's not obligatory that i use all types on it.

so using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() and getTypes for each assembly will not give me the right information.

I need just types which i used in the code.

I mean with the types used in the code the following situation:

> If i get Access to a static fields of a type or  If i instantiate the type.

Comment: Does instantiating a type via reflection based on its name in a string count? If so, the answer could be "all types", as the string might be supplied from the outside and hence could be anything. Likewise, instantiating a type via reflection could also be done the exact way you mention, by picking a type obtained via `GetTypes()`. This is commonly done for plugin systems or in other dynamic binding scenarios.

Comment: Yes it's basing on reflection but i load the assembly i'll use just one of the method by GetType() this method also depend on other types so i need to know this types and it's recursive.

If any other type in the assembly which i don't use or the type don't depend on it, so i don't have to count it.

Comment: Yes, *you* do that, but the assembly you're analyzing might well instantiate or use types with reflection, itself. Do you want to count such occurrences?

Comment: Yes all instantiation or calling static variable it will be recursive.